# Confusing output after use of increment operator

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{   
    int a[5] = {5,1,15,20,25};
    int i,j,m;
    i = ++a[1];
    j = a[1]++;
    m = a[i++];
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,m);
}
```

Okay now the program compiles and runs fine. But the output which i get is 3 2 15 i.e i =3 , j=2, m = 15. I don't understand how come the value of i becomes 3 as a[1] i.e '1' when incremented must become 2. This is a 'trace the output' type of question. I'm using gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written the values of the variables before and after the statement gets executes and 
all side effects have taken place.

```
int a[5] = {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
int i, j, m;

// before : i is indeterminate, a[1] = 1
i = ++a[1];  
// after: i = 2, a[1] = 2

// before: j indeterminate, a[1] = 2
j = a[1]++;  
// after: j = 2, a[1] = 3

// before: m indeterminate, i = 2
m = a[i++];  
// after: m = a[2] = 15, i = 3
```

Therefore, the final values are

```
i = 3
j = 2
m = 15
```

Answer (score 2):

When the following line is executed,

```
m = a[i++];
```

`i` is incremented again, making its value `3`.

Comment: oh yes. Thank you and thts why m return a[2] and thats 15 as i++ is post increment. m is assigned the value before i is incremented. But then j must be equal to '1' as value will be assigned first and then it will increment isnt it ?

Comment: The line `j = a[1]++;` can be interpreted as `j=a[1];a[1] = a[i]+1;`. The value of the expression `a[1]++`, which is assigned to `j`, is the value of `a[1]` before `a[1]` is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

On line 7, you have

```
i = ++a[1];
```

This increments `a[1]` (to 2), then assigns that to `i`.

Then on line 9, you have

```
m = a[i++];
```

This increments `i` (to 3), then assigns `a[3]` (15) to m.

Answer (score 0):

i = 3 because

```
i = ++a[1] => i = ++1 and so i,a[1] are both 2
m = a[i++] => i = 3 because of i++
```